# Change field using theme_preprocess_field()

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

gunwinner is my theme name and i want to change a field on particular content type.
I have tried this code,

```
function gunwinner_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if($element['#field_name'] == 'field_deal_url') {
     $values = $element['#items'][0]['value'];
     $deal_link = l(t("Go to Store"), "$values", array('attributes' => array('class' => 'store-link')));
     $element['#items'][0]['value'] = "Store";
  return;
  }
}
```

which returns me the array with the link title "Go to Store" but it doesn't reflect on the page for the particular field.

Can anyone help me out for this?

Answer (score 1):

You're making a copy of `$variables['element']` and manipulating that, so the changes aren't being persisted into the original variable.

Just change the first line of your function to

```
$element = &$variables['element'];
```